# How to use AD for authentication and use SQL database for authorization on .NET Core web app for Intranet

Tags: sql, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, role-base-authorization

I have a MVC .NetCore 3.0 web app that is using Windows Authentication, I want to add roles/permission to each user on a SQL database. My idea is to compare their AD user name to the database tables I create (User, Role, Permission). How can this be done? I have found documentation for users to create their own account, but not any using AD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `IClaimsTransformation` to associate your current windows authentication user with local database user , checking whether user's existence/roles/permissions , and you can also add user's custom claims(roles for example) to ClaimsPrincipal , so that you can directly that properties later from `User.Claims`:

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var id = ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity);

        var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, id.AuthenticationType, id.NameClaimType, id.RoleClaimType);

        //read database and create/check a user in local database , add custom claims  in Principal
        if (....)
        {
            ci.AddClaim(new Claim("localUserID", "XXX"));
        }
        else
        {
            ci.AddClaim(new Claim("localUserID", "XXXX"));

        }


        var cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(ci);

        return Task.FromResult(cp);
    }
}


 services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
```

Comment: I am new to .NET Core, would it be possible to provide a little more detail? I do not understand the if statement and add new Claim.

Comment: That is code sample , what you do is using ef to query the database to check the user/role , adding claim is not required if you don't want to add claims .

Comment: That is precisely what I need assistance with. Once set up how is it set up to work with the [Authorize(Roles="xxxx")] attribute?

Comment: Using EF to query database : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli . `[Authorize(Roles="xxxx")] ` will check ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType(http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role) , do you have that claim in your principle ?

Comment: I do not have that claim. Do I have to use IdentityDbContext for this to work?

Comment: If you are using asp.net core identity , see this : https://dotnetdetail.net/role-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core-3-0/